# Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jackson, s3-bucket

I am using AWS S3bucket and getting jars from this [link](https://javatutorial.net/java-s3-example). The problem is that my project have jackson 1.9 jars but this link give me jackson 2.6 jars and getting this

```
 Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration
```

**Is there is any way to use s3bucket jars compatible with Jackson 1.9?**

Thanks

Comment: I am facing similar type of issue. Does anyone have update on this.

Comment: @OPTIMUS for that we have install s3bucket at own linux server :-) , we are not using it via our code.